# Selenium can't find element by @FindBys annotation in case of two conditions

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects, findby

I have a text element on the page with properties:

[image: Web element property]

And I'm trying to get this element using FindBys annotation:

```
@FindBys({@FindBy(tagName = "h5"),@FindBy(id = "email_label")})
private WebElement EmailLabel;
```

but getting error:
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Cannot locate an element using By.chained({By.tagName: h5,By.id: email_label})

At the same time element is found properly if use just one condition:

```
@FindBys({@FindBy(id = "email_label")})
private WebElement EmailLabel;
```

or

```
@FindBys({@FindBy(tagName = "h5")})
private WebElement EmailLabel;
```

I use:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.59</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.59</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I also had issues with this kind of stuff lately. Wasn't doing it with Annotations. In my case, I suspect somehow the server didn't recognise the user agent - or realised it was being accessed as a crawler... and it didn't serve up the content for specific dynamic content. I looked to see if the cookies etc would shed light on things too... and gave up. I also tried searching for it by accessing the whole page content as a text string. It never appeared - and introduced delays/retries. Never recognised the nodes. Very frustrating!

Comment: I also had worries that the xpath selenium web driver recognises is 'complete'. was doing things like (//select)[2] - and a myriad of variations to look at the node. Never found it. CSS Selectors/XPath Selectors. Nothing worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### FindBys Annotation

[FindBys](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/FindBys.html) are used to mark a field on a [pageobjects](/questions/tagged/pageobjects) to indicate that lookup should use a series of `@FindBy` tags in a chain as described in `ByChained`. As an example:

```
@FindBys({@FindBy(id = "foo"),
      @FindBy(className = "bar")})
```

---

### Class ByChained

[ByChained](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/pagefactory/ByChained.html) mechanism used to locate elements within a document using a series of other lookups. This class will find all DOM elements that matches each of the locators in sequence, Asan example:

```
driver.findElements(new ByChained(by1, by2))
```

The above line of code will find all elements that match `by2` and appear **under** an element that matches `by1`. So essentially you shouldn't use both the `by` on the same node but one `by` for the *parent* node and the other for the *child* node and you can use the following *Locator Strategy*:

```
@FindBys({@FindBy(tagName = "h5"), @FindBy(tagName = "strong")})
private WebElement EmailLabel;
```

Ideally, to locate the `<span>` with text as **What's your email address?** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *css*:

  ```
  @FindBys({@FindBy(css  = "h5#email_label>strong"), @FindBy(tagName = "span")})
  private WebElement EmailLabel;
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  @FindBys({@FindBy(xpath  = "//h5[@id='email_label']/strong"), @FindBy(xpath = "//span[contains(., 'your email address')]")})
  private WebElement EmailLabel;
  ```